# How to prevent users from entering a variable directly into the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

**Index.html**

```
<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?file=" . $file . "' id="okok">

    <form action="do" method="post">
        <textarea class="source"><?php if(!empty($thesource))echo $thesource; ?>
    </textarea>
        </form>



<script>
$("#okok").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).val("href");
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                        $(".source").html(data); //or append }); });
</script>
```

Basically, what happens here is that when the user clicks on the link (a href="one.html"), it will display the contents of "one.html" into the textarea.

Once the user clicks on that link, the page will refresh and the URL will rewritten to http://example.com?file=one.html.

Since "one.html" is included in the variable 'file', it will gather all the contents included in the file "one.html" and display it in the textarea. In short, whatever is in the variable 'file' will have its contents displayed in the textarea.

The problem with this is that anyone can rename 'one.html' to something like 'do.php' from the URL, so now the contents in 'do.php' will be displayed in the textarea which means anyone can view the PHP code of that file.

How do I prevent the user from entering variables into the URL, or from entering any PHP file names into the URL?

I believe I could use htaccess but I'm not sure what to put in

Comment: Don't put the name of the file to be included in the URL. It solves this issue and fixes a *huge* security flaw in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control what requests someone will send to your server.

You need to either:

1. test to see if they are allowed to make a request before acting on it (e.g. have a list of filenames that are acceptable or have such a list and associate it with particular username/password combinations) *or*
2. hard code the value on the server

Comment: A third possibility exists: add a control code in the link (checksum)